# FieldDoesNotExist with OneToOne

Tags: django, one-to-one, photologue

I want to make gallery for users based on `Photologue` app. In order to connect users' profiles to photologue's models I want to use `OneToOne`. Also I want to ... lets say 'override' photologue's `get_absolute_url`, which is used by templates.

```
# models
from photologue.models import Gallery
from profiles.models import UserProfile

class GalleryExtended(models.Model):
    gallery = models.OneToOneField(Gallery)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, verbose_name=_('user'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profiles_user:profiles_gallery-details', args=[self.user.user_url, self.gallery.slug])

# views
from photologue.views import Gallery
from profiles.models import UserProfile
from .models import GalleryExtended, PhotoExtended

def get_user_gallery_queryset(self):
    user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user_url=self.kwargs['user_url'])
    gallery = Gallery.objects.filter(galleryextended__user=user)
    return gallery

class ProfileGalleryDateView(object):
    date_field = 'date_added'
    allow_empty = True

    get_queryset = get_user_gallery_queryset

# site.com/username/gallery (shows photos + images with a filter by year)
class ProfileGalleryPhotoArchiveIndexView(ProfileGalleryDateView, ArchiveIndexView):
    template_name = 'galleries/gallery_n_photo_archive.html'
```

So in view if I do

```
gallery = Gallery.objects.filter(galleryextended__user=user)
```

templates start to use Photologue's `get_absolute_url` (I do not use the core`photologue`s url `url(r'^photologue/', include('photologue.urls', namespace='photologue')),` as I integrate the app in my own url schema)

Is it possible to revert to something like this

```
gallery = GalleryExtended.objects.filter(user=user).***(get fields from Gallery)***
```

and avoid `django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: GalleryExtended has no field named 'date_added'` in order to start using `get_absolute_url` from `GalleryExtended`?

I know, it can easily be solved by extending `photologue`s model via inheritance, but I want to know if is it possible to use OneToOne? because in some sources I have read it is recommended to use 1to1 instead of inheritance.

Comment: I don't think you either understand your problem or made it very clear to us. The `FieldDoesNotExist` exception doesn't have much to do with model inheritance vs. OneToOne dilemma. Instead somewhere you're asking for `date_added` field value from `GalleryExtended`, but since that does not exist, you get the error message. Please tell us what you wish to achieve with this answer and we'll do our best.

Comment: @makaveli. Native `photologue`s model `Gallery` has some fields (including `date_added`). If I make QuerySet using `Gallery` model, `get_absolute_url` is used from `Gallery` model. I want to use `get_absolute_url` from `GalleryExtended` model, but this model does not have all fields the code requires. My question is: Is it possible to get fields (or maybe instanse, I do not know exactly) of `Gallery` model from the side of `GalleryExtended` model? Rephrased question can be: Is it possible to get with OneToOne something like inheritance, when one instance has all features of both models?

Comment: Well yes, if I understand you correctly, you are simply asking for `GalleryExtended.objects.filter(user=user).first().gallery.<field/method name>`, i.e. `GalleryExtended.objects.filter(user=user).first().gallery.title`. Am I right or not?

Comment: @makaveli Very close. I need to get all fields at once, not just one. Is it possible? Based on your example, somethings like GalleryExtended.objects.filter(user=user).first().gallery.<a‌​ll_fields>. I tried this `GalleryExtended.objects.filter(user=user).first().gallery`, but here I get `model object` and I have error `'Gallery' object has no attribute 'filter'`. I need somehow to get `QuerySet Object`

Comment: http://django-photologue.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/customising/models.html

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik I saw it. This would work if I did not need to integrate photologue to my own app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think I understand now what you want to do. And it's wrong and hacky and bad in each and every way.
First of all - model inheritance is nothing to be afraid of, in fact it's exactly the opposite. The hustle you're experiencing now is a great example of what's in store if you decide not to follow one of OOP's most important principles. Arguments such as "I read something from somewhere" can't really convert me and I truly recommend that you use inheritance instead of 1to1 relations. Not to mention that using 1to1 relation instead of inheritance also creates an extra DB query every time you need to use the objects in the same place.

Despite not recommending to carry on with this setup, I can give you some possible versions how to achieve sth similar to what you want. It's not perfect because it's not meant to be used this way.

If we're on the same page now, you have a structure such as this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def some_method(self):
        return self.name


class Model2(models.Model):
    first = models.OneToOneField(Model1, related_name='second')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def some_method(self):
        return self.name + '2345678'
```

You want to query out all the `Model2`s and call `Model1`'s `some_method()` on them (correct if wrong).
This can be achieved with a hacky solution when you replace the `self` argument with another model that fits the criteria.
I.e.

```
all_method_values = []
for obj in Model2.objects.all():
    all_method_values.append(Model1.some_method(obj))
```

So how to write this in a more pythonic way and still keep the 1to1 relation? Change the method in question to a static method with an argument and if you need to call it as a bound method of either models, make them call the same static method with respective arguments. But code says more than 1000 words:

```
# In the model
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return GalleryExtended.get_gallery_url(self.user.user_url, self.gallery.slug)

@staticmethod
def get_gallery_url(user_url, slug):
     return reverse('profiles_user:profiles_gallery-details', args=[self.user.user_url, self.gallery.slug])
```

Now, instead of the ugliness shown above, you can call without ugly hacking:

```
all_method_values = []
for obj in Model2.objects.all():
    all_method_values.append(Model1.get_gallery_url(obj.user.user_url, obj.gallery.slug))
```

For the record, I still recommend inheritance, but this works okay as well. Doing this small step removes the confusion of mixing two separate models' bound methods and clears up where the data is coming from.

Comment: authors of `two scoops of django` and creator of `django-photologue` in its docs say that inheritance is bad and 1to1 is better :)

Comment: @TitanFighter Can you give me a link or a quote? Surely they can't mean that for all cases and I'm wondering in what cases it could be true.

Comment: from 2 scoops - "At all costs, everyone should avoid multi-table inheritance since it adds both confusion and substantial overhead. Instead of multi-table inheritance, use explicit OneToOneFields and ForeignKeys between models so you can control when joins are traversed." - my fault. It is said about `multi`-table. Since one table is not multi, that's okey.

Comment: @TitanFighter Thank you for the quote. It is still multi-table inheritance since you have separate tables for the base object and child object (the base object isn't abstract). However we're not talking only about DB layer but also the Django logical operations and in my opinion choosing NOT to inherit from a base object just makes everything more confusing. Perhaps it's just my preference, but I still stand my ground that one should use model inheritance in this instance. Agreed - it would be better if the base class was abstract, but there's not much you can do about that.